# /null after axios call NUXT

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I have a project made with nuxt (v2), I am using @nuxt/axios and a backend in PHP.

The problem is that when I ask for data to the API in the *asyncData* I receive my data normally without any problem and my page is rendered nicely but after that, in my console sometimes I have a call to /null like *localhost:8080/null* and all my 'context' is null, I mean my parameters, my query strings everything.

For the moment I tried to only ignore the request to '/null' and not make any call to the endpoint if there is a '/null' path.

But now I am working with a middleware and there is the */null* call again.

Here an example of my console.

```
In server
Log Object { cookie_id: 123,
  fullpath: '/null',
  params: { negocio: 'null', tipoPropiedad: undefined, zona: undefined } }
```

Here is a picture of my pages if it helps:

[image: my nuxt pages/routes]

[image: mu nuxt pages/routes opened]

I have asyncData functions in the index and in the _negocio/_tipoPropiedad/_zona

It it helps in something I start working this project with nuxt v1 and then the nuxt v2 was released then I upgrade the project to v2, but the problem was in v2 and remains in v2, I was using the 'normal' axios library and the problem was there and I change it to @nuxt/axios and the problem remains.

I have weeks dealing with this problem, I have read my code many times, google it a lot and I don't find any possible answer to this. English is not my main language, sorry if there is some mistake.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any `<img>` tags that get their source set dynamically from the async data?

Comment: Yes, I render a lot of divs that have image tags inside them with the information that I got from asyncData

Comment: There's a good chance then that you have something like `<img :src="something">` and that `something` is `null` before your async data arrives. You should use some [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) to stop this from happening.